# Oscillating Electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, speed-of-light

Hypothetically, if I were to move at the speed of light, would I see an oscillating electromagnetic wave or photons oscillating or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The speed of light is always locally constant i.e. every observer measures the speed of light at their location to be $c$. Therefore there cannot be an observer who sees light to be stationary. There can be no observer who moves at the speed of light.

In fact it was when Einstein realised this that he discovered special relativity.

Comment: @vs_292: If I'm observing you moving then I can certainly observe you moving at very nearly the speed of light. But remember that I observe your length to be contracted and your time to be dilated. The result is that in your frame you still measure the speed of light to be $c$ no matter how closely I observe you to approach the speed of light.

Comment: Wow, that would mean that even I were to move at 99% the speed of light, I would still see light move at $c$ (in my frame)?

Comment: @vs_292: The fastest speed we have ever observed is the speed of protons in the LHC, which move at $0.99999999c$. However those protons would still measure the speed of light to be $c$ in their rest frame.

Comment: @vs_292, since motion is relative, there are an infinity of (locally) inertial reference frames in which you (as you read this) have speed arbitrarily close to $c$ and yet, you're completely unaware that you have this speed relative to these frames.  That's the very essence of the relativity of uniform motion.